# Get text from div and pass to the function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass div text in function using angular2

I have this in my template

```
<div (click)="logThis(this.text)">test</div>
```

and in component

```
logThis(x: any){
        console.log(x);
}
```

If I'll put some text instead of `this.text` it logs without any problem

I've tried this.value as well but it logs undefined

Other I've tried to add `<div #test (click)="logThis(test.text)">test</div>` but same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `this` in the template of a component. Your template variable approach is correct though but I think there is no `text` property:

```
<div (click)="logThis(div.innerText)" #div>test</div>
<div (click)="logThis(div.textContent)" #div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7SSYXsDLvXMxfJ2WB5Z) of component to add parameter on your function the element and get the inner text or inner html. If you want make this more dynamic you could create a directive.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2 #container (click)="GetContainerText(container)">Hello Container </h2>
          <div #container2 (click)="GetContainerText(container2)">Hello Container 2</div>
          <span #container3 (click)="GetContainerText(container3)">Hello Container 3</span>
        </div>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      constructor() {
      }

      GetContainerText(_container:HtmlElement){
        let _containerText = _container.innerText;
        let _containerHTML = _container.innerHTML;
      } 
    }
```

Why you want do this?? Maybe if you create a variable and bind on html be more simple for you. HTML is for view, not for coding. All you get from HTML must be an input. 90% of time you do something different is wrong and must think a more simple way.